# In google Maps API V3, How can I Prevent markers from repeating on x axis without using the limiting panning solution?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've been looking all over for the answer to this and I know that there is a way because leaflet does it in their framework. The thing is I am already using the Google APi and cannot turn back everything to leaflet plus I don't want to use leaflet and I cannot limit the boundaries as this would present some very odd and clunky solution to my map app. Does anybody know at all how to disable world wrapping on x-axis for google maps api v3? Again, please don't say about limiting panning and and bounds and step up the zooming. I've already tried this and this is not what I want, plus it really did not work well. If leaflet can do it with one porperty of worldwrap: false, then how can the same thing be achieved in Googles own framework?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've managed to do this is very crude.

First set the marker(s) to draggabble. Which stops the marker repeating longitudinally.

Then add a drag start and drag end handler.

on drag start, save the markers position.

on drag end, set the markers position back to its original position.

crude but seems to work.